# Is it relevant to make personalized 5** error pages?

Tags: php, apache, error-handling

I was following a tutorial to make personalized error pages with some lines like this in my apache conf:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 402 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 405 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 501 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 502 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 503 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 504 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 505 /errors/errors.php
```

and with some processing in the `error.php` based on `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]`.

So far so good.

But I wondered if the server encounters an internal error, will it be able to execute the `error.php` file?
Would it be smarter to provide `error.html` files in this case?

And I have a final question: how can I test those directives? How do I simulate errors other than 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a valid concern that if the server is already generating 500-level errors that the server may not be capable of running the PHP script. The way that it has been solved where I work is:

1. Create your `error.php` page.
2. Create a cron job that periodically captures `error.php` to a static `error.html` page.
3. Set `error.html` as your 500-level error page in Apache.

The reason we have this as a cron job is so that is changes are made to the general layout or surrounding content by our application those changes are captured without human intervention.

Comment: +1 for the mention of using crons for that. I use a custom 503 error page, but that doesn't factor in an internal server error code. So your method sounds great.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea on how to test this? I mean how to provoke a 500-level error page in Apache, if possible? The method proposed by Samuel doesn't seem to work since it's on php level.

Comment: You don't *provoke* a 500 error, you write a normal page that *pretends* it's a 500 error, then periodically save a static copy of that page via cron.

Answer (score 0):

Yes 5** pages will be generated with a custom **PHP** page.
To simulate a 5** and 4** error just use the headers like this :

```
<?php header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error'); ?>
```

More informations about headers [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

There are some nice examples [there](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/headers.htm).

**Note** : Overriding error pages will make you loose the error messages unless you handle them manually.